# Checkstyle configuration for TypeNameCheck

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am using the below configuration in my `check-style.xml` file which was imported in Eclipse but I did not get what is the meaning of below module:

```
<module name="TypeNameCheck">
      <!-- Validates static, final fields against the
      expression "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$". -->
      <metadata name="altname" value="TypeName"/>
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
```

Is it checks for Type(Static , final) or variable names. I googled it but I did not get any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Comment in your configuration is wrong. According to [Checkstyle Naming Conventions](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#Modules) checks page `<module name="TypeName">` validates identifiers for **classes, interfaces, enums and annotations** if they are in format `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`.

For `static final` fields there is `ConstantName` check available.